# obtener base numérica del eje de la gráfica

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Necesito obtener la base numérica del eje "y" de la gráfica para guardarlo en un variable y poder operar con él más adelante, en este caso es "1e-6", pero la realidad es que siempre varía ya que estoy trabajando con archivos .csv con más de cien columnas y miles de datos por columnas. Hice este código aparte solamente para que podamos enfocarnos en el problema principal.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0.000001,0.000002,0.000003,0.000004,0.000005]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 4))
axs.plot(x,y)

"""

base_number = axs.get_base_number() -> existe algún método de este tipo para conseguir la base? 

"""

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: gráfica matplotlib, numero base del eje]

Comment: esta pregunta ha sido respondida en esta publicación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851738/get-number-base-of-graph-axis/68852454#68852454

Comment: ¿por què tienes 2 cuentas con el mismo nombre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien te han dicho en los comentarios esa pregunta ya existe en el sitio en ingles, tu pregunta es exactamente igual a la otra por lo que podemos considerar que la has traducido y publicado aquí, como dato estas preguntas deben de ser auto respondidas. Hago la respuesta simplemente para que haya una respuesta en español.

Al tener una instancia `AxesSubplot` (almacenada en la variable `axs`) podemos acceder a distintos atributos de la gráfica, como lo es el pequeño string que se muestra en la parte superior de la gráfica (en el eje Y llamado offset). Para acceder a la información del eje Y utilizamos el método `yaxis` y luego accedemos al texto que muestra con `get_offset_text()`. Esto devuelve una instancia de `Text()` que contiene distintos valores, pero solo nos interesa el texto. Pero todo esto debe ser

```py
#obtenemos el texto con el método get_text()
exponent = axs.yaxis.get_offset_text().get_text()
print(exponent)
```

Y como resultado obtendremos:

```
1e-6
```

Esto ya es un string y puedes manejarlo como quieras, ya sea sacando partes de este o modificándolo a tu gusto.

Algo que muestra la respuesta en ingles es cambiar `fig.tight_layout()` por `plt.tight_layout()` pero no es necesario.

Comment: yo publiqué en el de español e ingles, y como en el de ingles me respondieron primero, un admin me había dicho que en este caso tengo que citar el link de donde obtuve la respuesta, me disculpo si no era de esta manera.

Comment: jeje, no te preocupes, igual es una pregunta muy interesante!